# Authorize only 2 files in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to authorize only 2 things in .htaccess:

- `/favicon.ico` -> deliver the file
- `/<anythingelse>` -> index.php

Therefore, `/logs/mylog.log` and `/hello.py` should go to index.php, instead of displaying the raw content of these files (that do exist!).

How to do such a .htaccess?

---

I tried:

Solution #1 (seems to create an infinite loop):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !favicon\.ico$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Solution #2 (delivers the /logs/mylog.log and /hello.py file, this should not happen!):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !favicon\.ico$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

Removed the lines checking if it was an existing file or directory, since you want those to get rewritten too.

Added a check that it is not already index.php to avoid a loop.

Changed the RewrieCond syntax to a simple comparison which is more legible.

Added forward slash at the start of the request uri matches or they wouldn't match.

Removed the capturing in the RewriteRule which you're not using.

**Update**

On further discussion in comments, this should work when a copy of the `.htaccess` file is placed in a subdirectory. Here is an update so that will work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(?:favicon\.ico|index\.php)$ index.php [END]
```

The RewriteCond directives couldn't be used without adding the directory name to them, since `/index\.php$` was an option but would also match the file in a subdirectory. The above acheives the goal without having to be updated when copied around, albeit not very pretty.

Comment: Why the slash in `!=/index.php`? `index.php` is not always at the root of my website. i.e. would it work for both `example.com/mywebsite/index.php` and `example.com/index.php` ?

Comment: `/mywebsite/index.php` would get rewritten to `/index.php` as with anything else. Do you mean you want `index.php` to be specific to each directory? So things in a directory get rewritten to `index.php` in that directory? That's quite a different, more complicated thing and I can update my answer if that is the case.

Comment: Let's say I have `example.com/anotherwebsite/` (not important here) and `example.com/mywebsite/` which contains the `example.com/mywebsite/.htaccess` I'm talking about. Then I don't want `example.com/mywebsite/` to be redirected to `example.com/index.php` but to `example.com/mywebsite/index.php`.

Comment: Ok sure, so it should work in a subdirectory but only when the htaccess file is placed there. Otherwise anything in a subdirectory gets rewritten to index.php in the lowest level directory with the htaccess file. I updated the answer to do that. The END flag is important or it will get rewritten again by the htaccess file higher up the directory structure.